# What can slow down Apache Camel's ActiveMQ message sending?

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Recently, I have performance problem with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ where there's lots of message in pending queue.
So I have add logs to print out Apache Camel message history when there's a performance problem with the time used in each steps. And from the log below, it is the sending message to ActiveMq part which took more than 50 seconds to finish.

```
....
activemqShared:sendToQueueA : 50699 ms, timeStamp : 10:08:43.173,
activemqShared:sendToQueueB : 59010 ms, timeStamp : 10:09:33.872,
```

And That part of the Camel route is like this

```
...
.to("activemqShared:sendToQueueA")
.to("activemqShared:sendToQueueB)
```

Basically this part should just send the message to ActiveMq and that's finished. Then there're consumers that would receive the tasks to be processed asynchronously.

So what can cause sending a message to ActiveMQ take such a long time? My speculation right now is network problem or something that make camel not receive notification that the message has been processed (?)

Comment: Did you look at the broker too? Camel just sends the message. My first guess is that the broker takes a long time to confirm that it has received the message. For example in a persistent config this includes saving the message to the message store.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ActiveMq. How can I confirm if it's a problem on the broker side or how can I reproduce that on my test environment?

Comment: I would start looking at the broker logs for the critical time frames when delivery takes such a long time. If there is nothing, try using an activemq started on your development machine (with out-of-the-box config) and see if the problem still occurs. You can use a Camel timer endpoint to produce as much messages as you like. If you have the same problem, it is probably the message sender. If not, it points to the broker configuration.

Comment: Is your AMQ broker set up to create back-pressure with [producer flow-control](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html)?